# Why does this rocket stop rolling while going up

Tags: rocket-science

I have been watching a ludicrous video about this insane notion of a flat earth and, among a lot of wrong and ill presented proofs (some fake ones) there is an interesting one which I don't have the knowledge to debunk.

In the video, at the half hour mark (https://youtu.be/PItu4aeGUrE?t=1775) we are shown an amateur rocket flying up straight into the sky, then the camera switches to the one strapped on the rocket, which is spinning while flying.

I can understand that the rocket flies straight instead of bending as space shuttles do (they have to in order to enter orbit) and the video cuts too early to start seeing the normal bending effect due to the earth rotation.

I can also understand that the rocket rolls in order to gain stability, but what I cannot understand is why the rocket STOPS rolling at some point. The video claims that it hit something and also stopped progressing, which is not really believable. What I believe is that it ran out of fuel and both the forward and the roll propulsion just stopped and the atmosphere simply acted as a brake (regardless of the claim that "rockets have no brake").

Is there any other possible explanation? Is my understanding of the roll correct? At one point I thought that maybe the rocket did not have a propulsion system that induced the roll but only used the fins to roll, but that will make explaining the abrupt stop harder.

Comment: If there is some technical reason,  and this was a deliberate feature of the flight, this question is *off topic* here - you would do better asking at Space Exploration SE. See https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/17089/how-did-the-gofast-2014-rocket-de-spin

Comment: @sammygerbil - We have questions here about figure skaters increasing their spin rate by pulling their arms in and slowing their spin by extending their arms. Those have been deemed to be on-topic. This is exactly the same thing, with the arms replaced by masses on strings.

Comment: @DavidHammen This is not such a question. It is not asking for an explanation of the physics behind the yoyo de-spin device. It is asking what caused the rocket to stop spinning. Which you answered by identifying the device from your knowledge of space exploration. Without such specialised knowledge the question is unanswerable, however good your understanding of physics.

Comment: Sorry guys, I was looking at Science and Physics SE and did not notice a SpaceExploration one... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spin was stopped by a [yo-yo despin device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yo-yo_de-spin). A yo-yo despin device releases a pair of tethered masses. The tether becomes rigid due to tension when the masses are fully deployed, thereby significantly increasing the moment of inertia about the roll axis. Think of how figure skaters stop their rapid spin by extending their arms.

Comment: I know the effect yes and it makes perfect sense... I suddenly feel like a fool to not have thought about that and to have almost believed the questionable claim that rockets have "no brakes"... I did not even realise that this was a known video from other sources just presented in a way to fool spectators (as all the other clips in that video). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

"But what I cannot understand is why the rocket STOPS rolling at some point."

It could be an illusion. When the spinning rate starts to match the frame rate of the camera, the image will start aliasing and it will look as it is actually rotating slower.

Check out these videos where the play with this "stroboscopic" effect: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uENITui5_jU

edit: The wikipedia article is also quite informative:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stroboscopic_effect

Comment: It's not an illusion, and it's not photoshopped, either. You can see this, without the flat earth nonsense, in the video released by the developers of this rocker: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=001IXnp0ogc . The rocket definitely stopped spinning abruptly, and it did so without hitting a non-existent barrier.

Comment: True that. When I first answered I stopped watching the video when I saw Bill Nye. Something definitely makes the rocket stop rolling.